# How to get selected shipping method in the checkout page magento 2?

Tags: magento-2.1, checkout, shipping-methods

I would like to get the selected shipping method from the checkout page it looks like this one :

[image]

I just want to get the selected shipping method like above image shown : **Shipping Table Rates** so that I can get the shipping code method.

I have some clue to get it using `\Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterfaceFactory` but when I add this to my block class I got this error :

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 3 passed to
>   Fabelio\Checkout\Block\ExpectedDelivery::__construct() must be an
>   instance of
>   Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterfaceFactory

Is this the correct way to getting the shipping method from checkout page ?

Comment: You should remove old files from the `var/generation/` directory.

Comment: @SiarheyUchukhlebau nope not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by calling the `Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingMethodInterface`. Add it to your constructor and get it by using this code :

```
 protected $shippingMethod;

public function __construct(ShippingMethodInterface $shippingMethod){
    $this->shippingMethod = $shippingMethod;
} 

// call you code in the methos somewehre like this : 
$methodTitle = $this->shippingMethod->getMethodTitle();
```

Comment: I got null value @GujaratSantana