# How can i get selected shipping method on checkout Magento2?

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping-methods

I am on checkout page and i want to get the shipping method that is selected by the user on which i can further add or extend functionality on the basis of shipping method choose?

Comment: please check this link , this might help you  - > https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/195309/how-to-get-selected-shipping-method-in-the-checkout-page-magento-2

Comment: @RahulMakwana do you in which controller need to use that code of the above link?

Comment: have you created any custom module ?

Comment: No if i will create then when i will select shipping method on checkout page how my controller will capture this?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108594/magento-2-enable-cash-on-delivery-only-for-specific-shipment-method/189530#189530 , This might help you